# Android: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when parsing JSON Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, exception

Forgive for I am new to Android and a novice at Java. I am trying to create a dynamic list view using data from a MySQL server. However, sometimes a query returns only one result. When my adapter class parses a JSONArray with one element to a String array, I receive an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. How do I avoid using an empty string in my resultArray to compensate for the exception? I don't want to use the empty string because it will still be selectable within the listview.

Parsing code:

```
    try
    {
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        // Taking a peek at the contents
        Log.e("log_tag", jArray.getJSONObject(0).getString(queryID));

        //For some reason if I don't do this
        // I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
        if (jArray.length() == 1)
        {   
            resultArray = new String[2];
            resultArray[1] = "";
        }
        else    
            resultArray = new String[jArray.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
        {
            resultArray[i] =   jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(queryID);      
        }
    }   

    catch(JSONException e)
    {
        throw new NullResultFromServerException("No results from server."); 
    }
```

Comment: Please add stack trace and mention where exactly do you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
        {
              String empty= jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(queryID);
              empty=empty.trim(); //this will remove the blank white space
           if(!empty.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
              resultArray[i] =   empty;  
        }
```